# In Postgres, can you create local table based on remote tabls schema using dblink?

Tags: postgresql

Currently, I am using the following command to create a table schema, based on another table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE schema_1.MynewTable (LIKE schema_2.TheoldTable INCLUDING ALL);
```

This works great. Now, however the "source" table is in a different server/db.
I have setup dblink extension, but I can't find an easy way to use it to create a local table based on remote table schema. What I'd like to be able to do is something like.

```
CREATE TABLE schema_1.MynewTable (LIKE remoteServer.schema_2.TheoldTable INCLUDING ALL);
```

where I would define the connection details for remoteServer

Is this possible? Or Do I need to manually extract the create script and use that to create the new table...which is a bit of a pain.

I'm currently on Postgres 11

Comment: Why not use [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html)?

Comment: I'm not looking to just access the remote table. I'm looking to make a local copy of it, which can then be modified, changed, etc.

Comment: Then I think you are between a rock and a hard place. `dblink` from what I remember is for operating on the remote server, not pulling DDL over to the local server. `postgres_fdw` brings the remote table to the local server where you can use it as a local object. There is nothing stopping you from dropping the foreign table once you have cloned it. Myself I keep my DDL in text files managed by [Sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) to avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: When using postgres_fdw you also get the IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA functionality.